# ExpressionEngine: Embed and filter

Tags: expressionengine

I got "Data/.List" file with content:

```
<!-- SubList 1 -->
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="1" e_cat="cat1" e_name="A"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="2" e_cat="cat2" e_name="B"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="3" e_cat="cat3" e_name="C"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="4" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="D"}
<!-- SubList 2 -->
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="11" e_cat="cat2" e_name="E"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="12" e_cat="cat3" e_name="F"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="13" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="G"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="14" e_cat="cat1|cat2" e_name="H"}
```

and in index I want to embed and render filtered elements:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="categories"}
<section>
    {name}
    {embed="Data/.List" e_cat="{id}"}
</section>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And I want to achieve:

Category1:
A, D, G, H

Category2:
B, E, H

Category3:
C, D, F, G

**I cannot change Data/.List**

So how can I achieve this result or with which query should i look for solution (tried: "ee conditional embed", "static embed", "filter embed")

---

I'm using channel to easily add new categories with "order" field

Channel Category is using id field (eg. "cat1")

Data/.List is like "row file" for me,

so I will write simple script to parse it to file like this

```
{if embed:cat == "cat1"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="1" e_cat="cat1" e_name="A"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="4" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="D"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="13" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="G"}
...
{/if}

{if embed:cat == "cat2"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="2" e_cat="cat2" e_name="B"}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming {id} from index is e_id specified in Data/.List...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="categories"}
  <section>
    {name}
      {if id == 1}
        {embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat{id}" e_name="A"}
      {if:elseif id == 2}
        {embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat{id}" e_name="B"}
      {if:elseif id == 3}
        {embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat{id}" e_name="C"}
      {if:elseif id == 4}
        {embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="D"}
      {if:elseif id == 11}
        {embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat2" e_name="E"}
      {if:elseif id == 12}
        {embed="Core/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat3" e_name="F"}
      {if:elseif id == 13}
        {embed="Core/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="G"}
      {if:elseif id == 14}
        {embed="Core/.ListThumb" e_id="{id}" e_cat="cat1|cat2" e_name="H"}
      {/if}
  </section>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thus bypassing the template you mentioned can't be changed because it's impossible to deliver what you want without avoid it or changing it.

If this answer is still way off your requirement, we need more information as to what is the end objective and data structure as I think the current approach is the problem, as there are too many fundamental questions with it...

Why not use relationships?

Why have you got a channel called "categories" instead of using native categories?

You have a channel called categories, but then you're hard coding the e_cat in the template - surely this value should be part of the categories data?

Why can't you change Data/.List? This is the template that's causing all the issues!

Is the intention to use different template groups with Element and Core, or is that a mistake?

Comment: I'm using channel to easily add new categories with "order" field

Channel Category is using id field (eg. "cat1")

Data/.List is like "row file" for me,

so I will write simple script to parse it to file like this

{if embed:cat == "cat1"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="1" e_cat="cat1" e_name="A"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="4" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="D"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="13" e_cat="cat1|cat3" e_name="G"}
...
{/if}

{if embed:cat == "cat2"}
{embed="Element/.ListThumb" e_id="2" e_cat="cat2" e_name="B"}
...